# Virtualbox installation error in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8

Tags: python, repository, virtualbox, redhat, rhel

I need to install Virtualbox in RHEL 8 which has a Developer Subscription. Since /etc/yum.repos.d/virtualbox.repo doesn't find http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/rpm/el/8/$basearch I did download rpm directly from virtuallbox with link, http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/rpm/rhel/7/x86_64/VirtualBox-6.0-6.0.8_130520_el7-1.x86_64.rpm.

But again I got this error saying,

```
Error: 
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libpython2.6.so.1.0()(64bit) needed by VirtualBox-6.0-6.0.8_130520_el6-1.x86_64
  - nothing provides python(abi) = 2.6 needed by VirtualBox-6.0-6.0.8_130520_el6-1.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

I found out RHEL 8 supports Python2 and Python3 but no idea about Python. Is there anyway to install Virtualbox in RHEL 8?

Answer (score 0):

Installing the RPM package requires to satisfy the dependencies. As you are downloading a single RPM file and don't have a repo from where to get the dependencies it won't work without some other steps.

The easier way, if you don't mind adding external third-party repositories, is to add the RPM Fusion repositories

### What is RPM Fusion?

RPM Fusion is a repository of add-on packages for Fedora and EL+EPEL maintained by a group of volunteers. RPM Fusion is not a standalone repository, but an extension of Fedora. RPM Fusion distributes packages that have been deemed unacceptable to Fedora.

### Enable RPM Fusion repositories in RHEL 8 or CentOS 8:

```
sudo yum localinstall --nogpgcheck https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-8.noarch.rpm https://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/el/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-8.noarch.rpm
```

### Install VirtualBox:

```
# notice the uppercase V and B
yum install VirtualBox

# add your user to the vboxusers group:
usermod -a -G vboxusers $username
```

### Alternative: Use Virt-Manager with KVM

Check the [following article in Red Hat Developers portal on how to configure Virt-Manager and KVM for virtual machines](https://developers.redhat.com/products/rhel/hello-world#fndtn-kvm). It's just as easy as VirtualBox and better supported, as this is how real Virtual Machines run in servers.

You can read more about the RPM Fusion repository [here](https://rpmfusion.org).

If you want to try Virt-Manager and need a hand, leave me a comment.